# Keeping Root open after piping

Tags: c++, sh, root-framework

I'm using ROOT version 5.34/30 as a C/C++ interpreter for a program that creates an image on a TCanvas. I'm using a shell script to open ROOT and call the function, but the second everything is run, ROOT closes and the TCanvas goes away, since the memory holding the canvas is wiped when you quit ROOT. I was wondering if there was any way to keep ROOT open, either by putting something at the end of the function I call, or by adding to my script.

This is essentially all that my script is:

```
echo -e ".L file.C \n foo()" | root -l
```

I've tried doing something like:

```
root -l
.L file.C
foo()
```

but this doesn't work, as root will open and then wait for user input instead of reading the next line, and it only goes to the next line once ROOT closes. Thus, the .L file.C and foo() are undefined. Anyone know how to pause the script or maybe call some ROOT TCanvas function that keeps it open? I've tried a few things and had no luck.

Comment: run it in the root console or use a `std::cin >> someDummyValue` at the end

Comment: Why not just do `root -l file.C`. Is there a particular reason for piping?

Comment: I've tried using cin >> randomValue, but that always takes in an EOF or void and quits root. If I do root -l file.C, root will not take in the following lines in the script.

Comment: following the suggestion to run `root -l file.C`, `root <filename>.XYZ` looks attempts to execute a function `<filename>()` after loading the file, so `root -l file.C` will run `foo()` if you wrap it into a `void file() {foo();}` function.